# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when loading a NSArray list ObjectAtIndex

Tags: ios, memory-management, objective-c++

my code throws an exception with ARC enabled when loading a list of shared user worlds. It's an EXC_BAD_ACCESS and throws a different message each time (either 0xe or EXC_I386_GPLFT). I've no idea how to even begin sorting this out and I can give as much information as is necessary. Thanks in advance.

Below is the entire function t give it context, sorry it's a bit of a wall!

I now get a new error after messing around. I can now get into the list but it now crashes on a new seperate function with i386_invop when moving between two different lists by tapping an arrow at the top of the page. It crashes here:

```
void statusbar::setStatus(NSString* status,float time,NSTextAlignment align){
    if(message&&[status isEqualToString:message]){
        textlife=time;       
        return;

    }

    clear();
    if(CHECK_GL_ERROR()){}
    message=status;
    if(IS_IPAD){
        text=new Texture2D(status,
                                    CGSizeMake(pos.size.width*SCALE_WIDTH,
                                                          pos.size.height*SCALE_HEIGHT) ,
                                    align,
                                         [UIFont systemFontOfSize:font_size*2]);
    }
    else{
    text=new Texture2D(status,
                                CGSizeMake(pos.size.width,
                                                      pos.size.height) ,
                                 align,
                                      [UIFont systemFontOfSize:font_size]);
    }
    textlife=time;

    //printg("message set:%s time:%f\n",[message cString],textlife);
}
```

[image: Here is the other part]

Comment: At least point out where the error happens.

Comment: Andtryaddingsomewhitespace.Itwillbeeasiertoread.

Comment: Error happens on the first line, and check the image at the bottom.

Comment: Sorry about the whitespace thing I'm new to this site

Comment: The whitespace has nothing to do with this site. It's about readable code - for your own sake as well as anyone else that needs to read it.

Comment: try running with address sanitizer